# Java RTP Video Streaming frame by frame

Tags: java, video, streaming, frame, rtp

I have a source server that for each mp4 video generate all its frames in jpg format in this way:

```
    FFmpegFrameGrabber frameGrabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber("C:\\Test.mp4");
    frameGrabber.setFormat("mp4");
    frameGrabber.start();
    IplImage i;
    try {
        for(int ii=0;ii<frameGrabber.getLengthInFrames();ii++){
            i = frameGrabber.grab();
            BufferedImage  bi = i.getBufferedImage();
            String path = "C:\\Frames\\"+ii+".jpg";
            ImageIO.write(bi,"jpg", new File(path));
        }
        frameGrabber.stop();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I want to build a client that stream the video via rtp frame by frame. 
How can I do that? I can't find useful libraries, neither good examples.
Thanks!

Comment: if you found a solution for this, may you share it please?